# Data abstraction and encapsulation benefits

Tags: c++, class, oop, interface, implementation

I have two points to ask and get cleared (from **C++ Primer**):

> 1: Class internals are protected from inadvertent user-level errors,
>   which might corrupt the state of the object.
>
> 2: The class implementation may evolve over time in response to changing
>   requirements or bug reports without requiring change in user-level
>   code.

Now for the first point I can think of `cin` or any other I/O object whose state might get corrupt due to wrong data but still I don't understand how is *class internal protected*. Second point is totally unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The statement uses "corrupt the state" in a very general sense that the values of member variables deviate the expectations of the methods using them. Consider a member variable that is not public: you set it in the constructor, and you modify it in member functions. Therefore, whatever value the member variable has, it has been assigned by your code alone. Assuming that your code is correct, the state of the variable is always what your code expects it to be. Public member variables, on the other hand, could be changed by the code that uses your class. Each time your code references such variable it runs the risk of finding a value set by someone else's code. In situations when not all possible values are considered correct, your member functions must assume that the value in a public member variable is invalid.
2. This is a way of saying that if you decide to change a meaning of a member variable, replace it with new member variables, or remove it from the implementation, you can do it only as long as the variable is private. Public member variables do not offer you such protection, because if you rename or remove them, external code that uses them stops compiling. Even worse situation happens when you decide to change the meaning of the variable without renaming it. In cases like that the external code would still compile, but your code would end up with corrupted state, as described in #1 above.

Comment: Re: #2: *external code that uses them stops compiling* - that's the best case. Often it can still compile but more subtle bugs are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Each class (with rare exceptions) has an open interface and a closed implementation.

This allows to change the implementation without changing the open interface.

So users of the class will not need to change their code when the implementation was changed.

And relative to the standard class `std::cin` then it is not corrupted then the user entered a wrong data. Its internal state is stable. It just sets for users an error flag to inform them that they are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. The point is that any access to the object must pass via the public interface that should be defined in a safe way (think of it as a sort of firewall to the object internals).
2. That's a design aspect. The objects should have well-defined roles (exposed via the public interface). These roles should rarely (if at all) change during the evolution of software. The internal implementation might change due to variety of reasons (bugs/optimizations/etc.) but as long as the interface remains unchanged, the software should continue working without the need to change other modules. Encapsulation is a great way to make the software modular.